# Pytorch RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_index_select

Tags: runtime-error, gpu, pytorch, embedding

I am training a model that takes tokenized strings which are then passed through an embedding layer and an LSTM thereafter. However, there seems to be an error in the input, as it does not pass through the embedding layer.

```py
class DrugModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, hidden_dim, drug_embed_dim,
            lstm_layer, lstm_dropout, bi_lstm, linear_dropout, char_vocab_size,
            char_embed_dim, char_dropout, dist_fn, learning_rate,
            binary, is_mlp, weight_decay, is_graph, g_layer,
            g_hidden_dim, g_out_dim, g_dropout):

        super(DrugModel, self).__init__()

        # Save model configs
        self.drug_embed_dim = drug_embed_dim
        self.lstm_layer = lstm_layer
        self.char_dropout = char_dropout
        self.dist_fn = dist_fn
        self.binary = binary
        self.is_mlp = is_mlp
        self.is_graph = is_graph
        self.g_layer = g_layer
        self.g_dropout = g_dropout
        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

        # For one-hot encoded SMILES
        if not is_mlp:
            self.char_embed = nn.Embedding(char_vocab_size, char_embed_dim,
                                           padding_idx=0)
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(char_embed_dim, drug_embed_dim, lstm_layer,
                                bidirectional=False,
                                batch_first=True, dropout=lstm_dropout)
        # Distance function
        self.dist_fc = nn.Linear(drug_embed_dim, 1)

        if binary:
            # Binary Cross Entropy
            self.criterion = lambda x, y: y*torch.log(x) + (1-y)*torch.log(1-x)

    def init_lstm_h(self, batch_size):
        return (Variable(torch.zeros(
                self.lstm_layer*1, batch_size, self.drug_embed_dim)).cuda(),
                Variable(torch.zeros(
                self.lstm_layer*1, batch_size, self.drug_embed_dim)).cuda())

    # Set Siamese network as basic LSTM
    def siamese_sequence(self, inputs, length):
        # Character embedding
        inputs = inputs.long()
        inputs = inputs.cuda()

        self.char_embed = self.char_embed(inputs.to(self.device))
        c_embed = self.char_embed(inputs)
        # c_embed = F.dropout(c_embed, self.char_dropout)
        maxlen = inputs.size(1)

        if not self.training:
            # Sort c_embed
            _, sort_idx = torch.sort(length, dim=0, descending=True)
            _, unsort_idx = torch.sort(sort_idx, dim=0)
            maxlen = torch.max(length)

            # Pack padded sequence
            c_embed = c_embed.index_select(0, Variable(sort_idx).cuda())
            sorted_len = length.index_select(0, sort_idx).tolist()
            c_packed = pack_padded_sequence(c_embed, sorted_len, batch_first=True)

        else:
            c_packed = c_embed

        # Run LSTM
        init_lstm_h = self.init_lstm_h(inputs.size(0))
        lstm_out, states = self.lstm(c_packed, init_lstm_h)

        hidden = torch.transpose(states[0], 0, 1).contiguous().view(
                                 -1, 1 * self.drug_embed_dim)
        if not self.training:
            # Unsort hidden states
            outputs = hidden.index_select(0, Variable(unsort_idx).cuda())
        else:
            outputs = hidden

        return outputs

    def forward(self, key1, key2, targets, key1_len, key2_len, status, predict = False):
        if not self.is_mlp:
            output1 = self.siamese_sequence(key1, key1_len)
            output2 = self.siamese_sequence(key2, key2_len)
```

After instantiating the class I get the following error when passing the input through the embedding layer:

```
<ipython-input-128-432fcc7a1e39> in forward(self, key1, key2, targets, key1_len, key2_len, status, predict)
    129     def forward(self, key1, key2, targets, key1_len, key2_len, status, predict = False):
    130         if not self.is_mlp:
--> 131             output1 = self.siamese_sequence(key1, key1_len)
    132             output2 = self.siamese_sequence(key2, key2_len)
    133             set_trace()

<ipython-input-128-432fcc7a1e39> in siamese_sequence(self, inputs, length)
     74         inputs = inputs.cuda()
     75 
---> 76         self.char_embed = self.char_embed(inputs.to(self.device))
     77         set_trace()
     78         c_embed = self.char_embed(inputs)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    539             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    540         else:
--> 541             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    542         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    543             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py in forward(self, input)
    112         return F.embedding(
    113             input, self.weight, self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,
--> 114             self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1482         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1483         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1484     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1485 
   1486 

RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_index_select
```

despite the fact that the input (e.g. key1) has already been passed to cuda and has been transformed into long format:

```
tensor([[25, 33, 30,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
        [25,  7,  7,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
        [25,  7, 30,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
        ...,
        [25,  7, 33,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
        [25, 33, 41,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
        [25, 33, 41,  ...,  0,  0,  0]], device='cuda:0')
```

Comment: Just to clarfiy. After you instantiate `model = DrugModel()` and print `model.device` what does this return? And that output at the end is `key1`?

Comment: After instantiating the model and printing model.device I get: device(type='cuda'). The output at the end is key1, yes (will clarify it).

Comment: This is not a CUDA programming question. Please do not re-add the tag

Answer (score 6):

setting `model.device` to cuda does not change your inner module devices, so `self.lstm`, `self.char_embed`, and `self.dist_fc` are all still on cpu. correct way of doing it is by using `DrugModel().to(device)`

in general, it's better not to feed a `device` to your `model` and write it in a device-agnostic way. to make your `init_lstm_h` function device-agnostic you can use something like [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/which-device-is-model-tensor-stored-on/4908/15)

Answer (score 2):

in order to make nn work in cuda.
first step: we must set initial model to cuda

```
device = torch.device('cuda:1')
model = esm.ProteinBertModel(
    args,
    alphabet,
).to(device)
```

second step: we should  set loaded model to cuda

```
bert_model = bert_model.to(device)
```