# Pytorch C++ RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_index_select

Tags: c++, pytorch, runtime-error, embedding, libtorch

I am calculating word similarity using `torch::Embedding` module by pretrained wordvector (glove.300d) on Ubuntu 18.04LTS PyTorch C++ (1.5.1, CUDA 10.1). I believe I have moved everything I can to the GPU, but when I execute it, it still says (full error log on the end of the question):

```
Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for
  argument #1 'self' in call to _th_index_select
  (checked_dense_tensor_unwrap at /pytorch/aten/src/ATen/Utils.h:72)
```

I have checked my model initialization method in **main.cpp**, and it is okay if I only do initialization.

```cpp
SimilarityModel simiModel(args, 400000, 300);
simiModel.to(device);

//model forward
torch::Tensor data = ids.index({Slice(i*batch_size, (i+1)*batch_size), Slice()}).to(torch::kInt64).to(device);        //take a batch
tie(score, indice) = simiModel.forward(data);   //forward and transfer score, indice to cpu for further calculation
```

and this is how I define **SimilarityModel** in **Similarity.h**:

```cpp
class SimilarityModel : public torch::nn::Module {
    public:
        int64_t topk;       // num of top words;
        Dictionary dict;
        int64_t vocab_size;
        int64_t embedding_dim;
        torch::nn::Embedding embedding{nullptr};
        vector<vector<float> > vec_embed;

        SimilarityModel(unordered_map<string, string> args, int64_t vocab_size, int64_t embed_dim);
        tuple<torch::Tensor, torch::Tensor> forward(torch::Tensor x);
};
```

At the same time I have done embedding initialization in **SimilarityModel** function in **Similarity.cpp**:

```cpp
SimilarityModel::SimilarityModel(unordered_map<string, string> args, int64_t vocab_size, int64_t embed_dim)
        :embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim) {      //Embedding initialize
    
    this->topk = stoi(args["topk"]);
    vector<vector<float> > pre_embed;
    tie(pre_embed, dict) = loadwordvec(args);       //load pretrained wordvec from txt file

    this->vocab_size = int64_t(dict.size());
    this->embedding_dim = int64_t(pre_embed[0].size());
    this->vec_embed = pre_embed;
    this->dict = dict;

    vector<float> temp_embed;
    for(const auto& i : pre_embed)      //faltten to 1-d
        for(const auto& j : i)
            temp_embed.push_back(j);
    torch::Tensor data = torch::from_blob(temp_embed.data(), {this->vocab_size, this->embedding_dim}, torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kFloat32)).clone();   //vector to tensor    
    register_module("embedding", embedding);      
    this->embedding = embedding.from_pretrained(data, torch::nn::EmbeddingFromPretrainedOptions().freeze(true));
}
```

and **forward** function in **Similarity.cpp**:

```cpp
tuple<torch::Tensor, torch::Tensor> SimilarityModel::forward(torch::Tensor x) {     

    auto cuda_available = torch::cuda::is_available();      //copy to gpu
    torch::Device device(cuda_available ? torch::kCUDA : torch::kCPU);
    
    torch::Tensor wordvec;
    wordvec = this->embedding->forward(x).to(device);      //python:embedding(x)
    torch::Tensor similarity_score = wordvec.matmul(this->embedding->weight.transpose(0, 1)).to(device);
    torch::Tensor score, indice;
    tie(score, indice) = similarity_score.topk(this->topk, -1, true, true);        //Tensor.topk(int64_t k, int64_t dim, bool largest = true, bool sorted = true)

    score = score.to(device);
    indice = indice.to(device);
    score.slice(1, 1, score.size(1));       //Tensor.slice(int64_t dim, int64_t start, int64_t end, int64_t step)
    indice.slice(1, 1, indice.size(1));
    return {score.cpu(), indice.cpu()};   //transfer to cpu for further calculation
}
```

As for intermediate variables in **forward()** have been put to GPU too. However, I totally have no idea which one is left in CPU, and the error log does not help so much. I have tried the method in [Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_index_select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347111/pytorch-runtimeerror-expected-object-of-device-type-cuda-but-got-device-type-cp) to do `SimilarityModel().to(device)`, but that does not work. I am still having a hard time reading this error log and would like some instructions on how to debug such questions.

Error log:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::Error'
  what():  Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_index_select (checked_dense_tensor_unwrap at /pytorch/aten/src/ATen/Utils.h:72)
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string const&) + 0x46 (0x7fb566a27536 in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: <unknown function> + 0x101a80b (0x7fb520fa380b in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so)
frame #2: <unknown function> + 0x105009c (0x7fb520fd909c in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so)
frame #3: <unknown function> + 0xf9d76b (0x7fb520f2676b in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so)
frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x10c44e3 (0x7fb558d224e3 in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #5: at::native::embedding(at::Tensor const&, at::Tensor const&, long, bool, bool) + 0x2e2 (0x7fb558870712 in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #6: <unknown function> + 0x114ef9d (0x7fb558dacf9d in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #7: <unknown function> + 0x1187b4d (0x7fb558de5b4d in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #8: <unknown function> + 0x2bfe42f (0x7fb55a85c42f in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #9: <unknown function> + 0x1187b4d (0x7fb558de5b4d in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #10: <unknown function> + 0x32b63a9 (0x7fb55af143a9 in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #11: torch::nn::EmbeddingImpl::forward(at::Tensor const&) + 0x71 (0x7fb55af127b1 in /home/switchsyj/Downloads/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #12: SimilarityModel::forward(at::Tensor) + 0xa9 (0x55c96b8e5793 in ./demo)
frame #13: main + 0xaba (0x55c96b8bfe5c in ./demo)
frame #14: __libc_start_main + 0xe7 (0x7fb51edf5b97 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
frame #15: _start + 0x2a (0x55c96b8bd74a in ./demo)

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Are you sure `this->embedding` was moved to the GPU?

Comment: Not sure, but I noticed that there is no .device( ) function in c++API for Embedding class. And I can not put this in GPU by .cuda( ) or .to(device) also. I doubt that this->embedding is not in GPU too(someone said that .to(device) is not inplace operation), so I have tried to assemble them in the torch module by TORCH_MODULE(SimilarityModel) in SimilarityModel.h, and do simiModel->to(device) in main.cpp. At last, it comes to the same error.@Berriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, one of the two following `Tensor`s are not in the GPU when you're running `SimilarityModel::forward()`:

- `this->embedding->weight`
- `x`

Given that the error points to the `argument #1`, I'd say that `weight` is the one on the CPU.

Here's the call for [`index.select`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c0bfa45f9d26fb814a80f3053fbc550ff77d82c1/aten/src/ATen/native/Embedding.cpp#L14-L29):

```cpp
Tensor embedding(const Tensor & weight, const Tensor & indices,
                 int64_t padding_idx, bool scale_grad_by_freq, bool sparse) {
  auto indices_arg = TensorArg(indices, "indices", 1);
  checkScalarType("embedding", indices_arg, kLong);

  // TODO: use tensor.index() after improving perf
  if (indices.dim() == 1) {
    return weight.index_select(0, indices);
  }

  auto size = indices.sizes().vec();
  for (auto d : weight.sizes().slice(1)) {
    size.push_back(d);
  }
  return weight.index_select(0, indices.reshape(-1)).view(size);
}
```

First, try to directly move the weight to the GPU. If it works, it means that when you called `TORCH_MODULE(SimilarityModel)`, and moved the model to the device, it should have worked too. Remember that you have to change the name to `SimilarityModelImpl` (Name+Impl) in this case. Otherwise, it won't work as well.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot, next time I need to carefully check the source code.